# How to access NgRx store outside of Angular App

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Is there any way we can export NgRx store and use it from outside Angular app. Eg: dispatch an action of the store, or get the current state of the store.

In my case, I have angular store in an Angular App that is built using `@angular/elements`, the app is later used in another environment/framework, and I don't know how to access the store in this case.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: What about using public methods of your custom-element to access the store or dispatching actions?

Comment: You can use @output to export store "or desired part from it" with desired change

Comment: You can serialize the store in a key named `store` on `localStorage` and deserialize it where you need it.